# Can there be two ribbons in an Outlook VSTO Add-in?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm using the visual designer and have one custom ribbon with 12 or so buttons on it. I'd like to add the most important button from that ribbon onto "TabMail" so that I can use it more easily.

I have added another ribbon via the "add..." dialog, then ribbon, and then add a test button to it. When I then run the solution (from Visual Studio, debug or release) it seems to pick one ribbon or another to show - either leaving me missing a button, or missing 12!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of downvotes on this, and since this probably means it's out of scope or something, I am considering deleting it. I originally left the question though, as I thought it would help other people who had also used the wrong terminology and done a google search to fix issues - if this is still not appropriate for stack-overflow, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found that what I should be using is two *Tabs*, not two *Ribbons*. Each tab can appear wherever you want, rather than each having to come up as a separate custom tab.

Here's the setup inside visual studio:

[image: Screenshot from visual studio of configuration]

Shown below is "My Button" in blue, and in red is "My Tab"
[image: Screenshot from outlook showing the result]

Comment: Thank you for leaving the question, and the answer. I'm on a related quest and this was helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes here looking for information on how to combine ribbon from designer and e.g. context menu from XML it is apparently not possible. You have to choose one, or the other.

Source: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-vsto-is-it-possible-to-have-both-designer-and-xml-ribbons/ (has code snippets)

The recommendation is to change from the (older) designer approach to the (newer) XML approach.